# How to detect this change-point?

Tags: nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, change-point

Let $Y\in\{0,1\}$ be a binary random variable. Let $P(x_1,x_2)=E(Y|x_1,x_2)$. By definition we have $0 \leq P(x_1,x_2) \leq 1$. Suppose $P(x_1,x_2)$ is strictly monotone in $x_1,x_2$ and $P(x_1,x_2)=1$ if $x_1\geq \overline{x}^*_1$ and  $x_2\geq \overline{x}^*_2$, where $\overline{x}^*_1$ and $\overline{x}^*_2$ are two unobservable threshold in the support of $x_1$ and $x_2$. Note $(\overline{x}^*_1,\overline{x}^*_2)$ is a change-point for $P(x_1,x_2)$ as its partial derivatives changes to constant zero when $x_1$ and $x_2$ go beyond this point.

Suppose $x_1,x_2\in[\overline{x},\underline{x}]$ with strictly positive Lebesgue density everywhere, and $\overline{x}<\overline{x}^*_1<\overline{x}^*_2<\underline{x}$. Suppose we have a random sample $\{Y_i,X_{1i},X_{2i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$, where $Y_i=\mathbf{1}(e_{i1}\leq X_{1i}, e_{2i}\leq X_{2i})$ with $\mathbf{1}(\cdot)$ being the indicator function, and $e_{ki}$ is a random variable with support $[\overline{x},\overline{x}^*_{k}]$ for $k=1,2$. How can we consistently detect $\overline{x}^*_1$ and $\overline{x}^*_2$ using the sample information? Any comments, insights, or reference are welcome.

I know there is a literature on detecting change-point(like a point with changed derivative) for regression $Y_i=g(X_{1i},X_{2i})+e_i$, but I'm  not sure how this problem is related to mine. So some insights on the connection would be appreciated too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consistent estimators $(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2)$ for $(\overline{x}_1^*, \overline{x}_2^*)$ are given by
$$\textrm{Choose } \hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2 \textrm{ to maximise } \left(\underline{x} - \hat{x}_1\right)\left(\underline{x} - \hat{x}_2\right),$$
$$\textrm{subject to } \hat{x}_1 < \hat{x}_2 \textrm{ and } \vert\left\{(y_i, x_{1i}, x_{2i}) \mid x_{1i} > \hat{x}_1, x_{2i} > \hat{x}_2, y_i = 0\right\}\vert = 0.$$

That is, if you plotted the $(x_{1i}, x_{2i})$ points corresponding to $y_i = 0$ inside the rectangle $\left[\overline{x}, \underline{x}\right]^2$, you choose $\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2$ to make the empty rectangle in the top-right (with $x_1 > \hat{x}_1$ and $x_2 > \hat{x}_2$) as large as possible.

The estimator I gave above is consistent because it converges to the true values $(\overline{x}_1^*, \overline{x}_2^*)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. I will show that $P\left((\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2) \in [\overline{x}_1^* - \epsilon, \overline{x}_1^*] \times [\overline{x}_2^* - \epsilon, \overline{x}_2^*]\right) \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

In order to get $(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2) \in [\overline{x}_1^* - \epsilon, \overline{x}_1^*] \times [\overline{x}_2^* - \epsilon, \overline{x}_2^*]$ we need to have at least one point $(x_{1i}, x_{2i}) \in (\overline{x}_1^* - \epsilon, \underline{x}] \times (\overline{x}_2^* - \epsilon, \overline{x}_2^*)$ with $y_i = 0$, and at least one point $(x_{1i}, x_{2i}) \in (\overline{x}_1^* - \epsilon, \overline{x}_1^*) \times (\overline{x}_2^* - \epsilon, \underline{x}]$ with $y_i = 0$.

I will go through the first case: define $R = (\overline{x}_1^* - \epsilon, \underline{x}] \times (\overline{x}_2^* - \epsilon, \overline{x}_2^*)$. The area of $R$ is $(\underline{x} - \overline{x}_1^* + \epsilon)\epsilon > 0$, and $P(x, y) < 1$ in $R$ due to the strict monotonicity of $P$ outside  $[\overline{x}_1^*, \underline{x}] \times [\overline{x}_2^*, \underline{x}]$. So $P(Y = 0) > 0$ for $(X_1, X_2) \in R$. So for a random sample $(Y, X_{1}, X_{2})$, $P(((X_{1}, X_{2}) \in R) \wedge (Y = 0)) > 0$. Let this probability be called $\zeta$. The probability that after $n$ samples we have at least one point $(X_1, X_2) \in R$ with $Y = 0$ is $1 - (1 - \zeta)^n \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. The second case is similar. Hence our estimator is consistent.

In change-point analysis you generally either have a parametric model for both regimes or for neither. In this case, if we knew something about $P(x_1, x_2)$, e.g. $P(x_1, x_2) = c_1x_1 + x_2x_2$, capped above at $1$ and below at $0$, we could probably make an estimator that converged much faster, and made use of the $y = 1$ observations (since they are just thrown away with my estimator). My approach was inspired by the solution to the problem of finding the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ given data $X_i \sim \textrm{Uniform}(0, \theta)$. In that case the MLE is the maximum of the observed data. The likelihood of an estimator $\hat{\theta}$ there is $0$ if there is ever an observation $X_i > \hat{\theta}$, and in your puzzle, if we ever observe a sample with $Y_i = 0$ then we know that $\overline{x}_1^* > X_1, \overline{x}_2^* > X_2$. Another feature of this problem is that you keep observing data near to the change-points. If you imagine detecting a change-point in a time series $X_1, \dots, X_n$, so there is some unknown time $1 < \tau < n$ when the data distribution changes, the estimator will not necessarily be consistent. This is because more data $X_{-1}, X_{-2}, \dots$ or $X_{n +1}, X_{n+2}, \dots$, does tell you more about the parameters before and after the change, but you get no new data near the change point, which is the most useful data. If you keep getting fresh data near the change point then an estimator for it will be consistent.

Comment: Thanks! This solution looks interesting and insightful.

Comment: A few questions: 1. In the constraint do you mean $$\textrm{subject to } \hat{x}_1 < \hat{x}_2 \textrm{ and } \vert\left\{(x_{1i}, x_{2i}) \mid x_{1i} > \hat{x}_1, x_{2i} > \hat{x}_2, y_i = 0\right\}\vert = 0.$$ so that the two threshold we search for must make sure that no observations with $(x_{1i}, x_{2i}) $ going beyond have the corresponding $y_i=0$?

Comment: 2. In the beginning of the proof, should it be that " we need to have at least one point $(x_{1i},x_{2i})\in (\underline{x},\overline{x}^*_1-\epsilon)\times (\overline{x}^*_2-\epsilon,\overline{x}^*_2)$, and at least one point $(x_{1i},x_{2i})\in (\overline{x}^*_1-\epsilon,\overline{x}^*_1)\times (\underline{x},\overline{x}^*_2-\epsilon)$?

Comment: 3. I didn't quite understand the argument of the proof. Suppose $Q=(\overline{x}^*_1-\epsilon,\overline{x}^*_1)\times (\overline{x}^*_2-\epsilon,\overline{x}^*_2)$, as eventually we want to show that $Pr(\text{at least one observation satisfy} (X_{1i},X_{2i})\in Q, Y_i=0)\rightarrow 1$, why can't we do it as follows: by definition $Pr(\text{at least one observation satisfy} (X_{1i},X_{2i})\in Q and Y_i=0)=1-Pr(\text{all observations have} (X_{1i},X_{2i})\notin Q, \text{or}Y_i\neq0)=1-\eta^n \rightarrow 1$

Comment: Thanks for your comments
1. Yes, I mean $\hat{x}_1$ and $\hat{x}_2$ instead of $x_1$ and $x_2$.
2. You gave in the problem statement that $\overline{x}^*_1 < \underline{x}$, so the numbers in the bracket would be the wrong way round in that formula if I swapped $\overline{x}^*_1 - \epsilon$ and $\underline{x}$.
3. I agree that your proof is correct: by showing that the probability that $Q$ stays empty for $y_i = 0$ samples tends to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, you show that the estimator is consistent.

Comment: I see, my bad. $\overline{x}^*_1<\underline{x}$ was a typo, sorry for the confusions. But I will not change it so that it's still consistent with your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Btw, what do you think is the rate of convergence for your estimator?

Comment: Sorry I don't know where to start assessing the rate of convergence. I can only make the simple observation that the lower $P(x, y)$ is, the faster it will converge.

Comment: Hi, another question: in your proof, where did you use the fact that $\widehat{x}_1$, $\widehat{x}_2$ maximizes the area of the rectangle on the corner?

Comment: It is used, but not mentioned explicitly, in the paragraph that begins "In order to get...". It is actually an "if and only if" statement. We have $(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2) \in (\bar{x}^*_1 − \epsilon, \bar{x}^*_1] \times (\bar{x}^*_2 − \epsilon, \bar{x}^*_2]$ if and only if there is at least one point with $y_i = 0$ in the rectangle $(\overline{x}_1^* - \epsilon, \underline{x}] \times (\overline{x}_2^* - \epsilon, \overline{x}_2^*)$ and at least one point with $y_i = 0$ in the rectangle $(\overline{x}_1^* - \epsilon, \overline{x}_1^*) \times (\overline{x}_2^* - \epsilon, \underline{x}]$.

Comment: If each of those rectangles contains a point, then the largest possible rectangle in the top-right corner containing no points with $y_i = 0$ can't extend any further "south-west" than the point $(\bar{x}^*_1 - \epsilon, \bar{x}^*_2 - \epsilon)$. $\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2$ can't be chosen to be "north-east" of $(\bar{x}^*_1, \bar{x}^*_2)$ because there will be no points with $y_i = 0$ "north-east" of $(\bar{x}^*_1, \bar{x}^*_2)$, and so the rectangle can be made larger by choosing its bottom-left corner to be "south-west" of $(\bar{x}^*_1, \bar{x}^*_2)$.

Comment: Thanks! Back to an earlier question on convergence rate. Do you have any guesses or intuitions on where to start in deriving the rate of convergence?

Comment: The probability of observing a point in any region $Z$ is $\int_Z P(Y = 0 \mid X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2) f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2) dx_1 dx_2$, which equals $\int_Z (1 - P(x_1, x_2))/(\underline{x} - \overline{x})^2 dx_1 dx_2$, since the joint density of $X_1, X_2$ is uniform. So you can calculate, for any $\epsilon$, the probability of $(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2)$ being in the rectangle of area $\epsilon^2$ south west of the true parameters after $n$ observations.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful! The joint density of $X_1,X_2$ is not necessarily uniform, but I guess that's not a problem. I can always get this probability in terms of the joint density of $X_1,X_2$. My next question is:  How is this probability related to rate of convergence, i.e., the $n^\alpha$ such that $n^\alpha((\widehat{x}_1,\widehat{x}_2)-(\overline{x}^*_1,\overline{x}^*_2))$ converges to a random vector?

Comment: Since $(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2)$ is SW of $(\overline{x}^*_1, \overline{x}_2^*)$, the probability that $\|(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2) - (\overline{x}^*_1, \overline{x}_2^*)\|_2^2 < \epsilon^2$ is less than the probability that $(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2)$ is in the square SW of $(\overline{x}^*_1, \overline{x}_2^*)$ of area $\epsilon^2$, and greater than the probability that $(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2)$ is in the square SW of $(\overline{x}^*_1, \overline{x}_2^*)$ of area $\epsilon^2/2$.

Comment: Maybe these bounds could be used to bound the rate at which $(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2) - (\overline{x}^*_1, \overline{x}_2^*)$ converges to $(0, 0)$. But I'm not sure to be honest, this is just my intuition for how the convergence could be calculated.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the right place to start.